# How to pass repositories/distributionManagement configuration into pom.xml using command line

Tags: maven

I attempt to build a CI/CD pipeline that:

1. runs Swagger codegen that generates a Maven project of the client library.
2. runs `mvn deploy` to deploy the client lib to the remote repository.

However, the autogenerated `pom.xml` does not have the configuration of `<repositories>` and `<distributionManagement>`.

I am looking for a Maven-native solution to *programmatically* add `<repositories>` and `<distributionManagement>` configuration to this auto-generated `pom.xml`.

Autogenerated `pom.xml` that only lives in the lifecycle of a CI/CD build

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   ...
    <url>https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen</url>
    <description>Swagger Java</description>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:swagger-api/swagger-codegen.git</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:swagger-api/swagger-codegen.git</developerConnection>
        <url>https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen</url>
    </scm>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Unlicense</name>
            <url>http://unlicense.org</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <name>Swagger</name>
            <email>apiteam@swagger.io</email>
            <organization>Swagger</organization>
            <organizationUrl>http://swagger.io</organizationUrl>
        </developer>
    </developers>

    <build>
        ...
    </build>

    <profiles>
       ...
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
       ...
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        ...
    </properties>
</project>
```

The snippet I want to add into `pom.xml`:

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>...</id>
            <url>...</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>...</id>
            <url>...</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

Comment: If you pom does not have distributionManagement you simple should add it..

Comment: Thank you @khmarbaise, as I said the pom.xml only exists in the CI/CD build lifecycles, and I have to edit it programmatically.

Comment: I'm looking for a such solution ! Have you found a way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to achieve this by passing a command-line argument to mvn deploy:

```
mvn deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=ID::URL
```

- `ID` is the id of the server in your `settings.xml`
- `URL` is the URL of the deployment endpoint as you would use in `distributionManagement/url` part of your `pom.xml`.